# Is there any way to refactor this equation?

Tags: refactoring

I have a function produce this equation:

```
(-4*dt^2*(c3 + a3*t)^2*t0^4 + dxC^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2 + dxM^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2 + dxY^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)
```

Is there any way to force this to be:

```
(-dt^2)*(c3 + a3*t)^2 + (dxC^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4) +
(dxM^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4) + (dxY^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)
```

I'm hoping to construct a metric tensor from this and it's much easier to see how things factor out this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
expr = (-4*dt^2*(c3 + a3*t)^2*t0^4 + dxC^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2 + 
 dxM^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2 + dxY^2*(t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4*t0^4)//FullSimplify

Collect[expr, {dxC, dxM, dxY}, FullSimplify]
(*-dt^2 (c3 + a3 t)^2 + (dxC^2 (t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4 t0^4) + (dxM^2 (t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4 t0^4) + (dxY^2 (t0^2 + t1^2)^2)/(4 t0^4)*)
```

[image]

Comment: That's freaking awesome.  I had jury-rigged something using the **Coefficient** function, but that's much more elegant.